# ESB code coverage

Tags: code-coverage, esb

I want to do code coverage for an esb process. For instance if I have an itenary which has the main process A and subprocesses B and C. These processes have steps x,y,z,etc. I want to do a coverage on this itenary if I execute test cases. The coverage should show the steps which are executed and not executed and possibly the no of times they are executed. Is it possible to do this coverage.Any tools already available in the market?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) can help you. You install Java agent on your ESB JVM and run some functional/integration tests. JaCoCo collects information about all executed methods just like any other code coverage tool and dumps them to file in binary format.